# How to run console command inside php code using thread--Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii, scheduled-tasks, yii-extensions

I'm trying to schedule a task using PHP code in Yii Framework. I want to execute the below command line inside PHP code using some thread function at certain intervals of time.

This command is stored in one table along with the frequency with which it will be scheduled. I am using YII scheduler extensions. I don't want to run the console command manually or task scheduled in windows.

I want to run this using timer inside PHP code. Here's what I've tried so far-

```
yiic Scheduler run --name="Priorizer"

   Priorizer =  d:/xampp/php/php.exe d:/xampp/htdocs/Merged/cron.php Priorizer //stored in yii-schedules table
```

Comment: I want to run this /yiic Scheduler run through php code not in command line or Scheduled Tasks in windows.. I want to do this through php code

Comment: check this http://pk1.php.net/function.exec

Comment: Yes how to use thread to be run to execute this command in php (timer to check always whether any task is scheduled or not if so its executes this exec())

Comment: I want thread to check this yii-schedule table to find any task is scheduled now if so exec() command to run /yiic ... has to call

Comment: @zzlalani can you provide any link or idea to do this since am new to yii and php too ?

Comment: well sorry but i dont understand what you are trying to achive

Comment: I have table with last_run and next_run time i need to execute one thread for every 5 mins to check this table whether any task is ready to run or not ?

Comment: then use cron check in another php file and trigger the other file in that file with exec code..